# Mini-Batch Gradient Descent - Large batch size require small learning rate?

Tags: stochastic-gradient-descent

[Coursera Machine Learning in the Enterprise - Science of Machine Learning and Custom Training](https://www.coursera.org/learn/art-science-ml/exam/LfYwg/science-of-machine-learning-and-custom-training?redirectToCover=true) says large batch size require smaller LR.

[image]

However, [How should the learning rate change as the batch size change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033556/how-should-the-learning-rate-change-as-the-batch-size-change) suggests otherwise.

> However, recent experiments with large mini-batches suggest for a simpler linear scaling rule, i.e multiply your learning rate by k when using mini-batch size of kN. See P.Goyal et al.: Accurate, Large Minibatch SGD: Training ImageNet in 1 Hour https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02677

Which is correct? Large batch size requires large LR or Large batch size requires small LR.